# Alternative To Apple Dashcode

Tags: wysiwyg, mobile-website, dashcode

I've been using [Apple Dashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashcode) for some months while I was building iOS WebApps, but when I tried to use the same code on Android and it won't work. So I'm looking for an alternative that has the same power and simplicity of Dashcode, but it's cross-platform. Any suggestions?

I've already tested Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5, but it isn't WYSIWYG as Dashcode, where you can drag things into the preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencha Touch will give you a basic build and then you can target different devices. This is essentially JavaScript framework but you need to "learn" the framework

IuI and JQuery mobile are JavaScript libraries that you can use over the top of html and css.
However none of these have the same sort of IDE that Dashcode has although i believe Sencha is working towards one so you are into hand cranking the code.

I am slightly surprised that you say the Dashcode doesn't work on Android as i have written apps (web based) that work on both and underneath Dashcode is just html/css/javascript. Maybe try Daschcode without the Apple libraries and use JQuery Mobile to replace?? I have not tried that but had reports that it can be done.

You could also look at Sproutcore and Cappuccino, again JavaScript frameworks. However both have Apple associations. Cappuccino is  called Objective-J and it looks like Objective-C and Sproutcore was used to build Apples Mobile Me interface but both have moved on since then. Cappuccino has a GUI IDE but not sure on Sproutcore.